# How to sign an executable created with launch4j using sign4j?

Tags: java, inno-setup, sign, launch4j

I made an Application. I converted it into exe using launch4j and made an installer using Inno Setup. But when I run it, it is showing

> Do you want to install this application from unknown publisher?
> I searched Google and found that we need to sign the exe. I also found that we can do this with sign4j. But how can we do this? Also I have one doubt we need to sign the exe created by launch4j or Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `sign4j` to sign the program itself (the exe presumably) but use a standard tool like Microsoft's `signtool.exe` to sign the installer.

For my own work I do sign both the contents of any installer as well as the installer itself.

Comment: How can I do that using sign4j?